# Ruby 2.4.4 documentation missing

Tags: ruby, documentation, ri

My question is about the ruby-doc.org documentation, but also relates to the ri documentation lookup inside ruby.

I've already read dozens of similar questions/answers about the ri not working and giving "nothing known" messages and I've tried to follow some of that old advice. It just seems that those old answers aren't applicable to me.
One was to install the rdoc --all --ri from the ruby root directory. I tried that and it failed (unable to convert to UTF8 or something like that).
Another suggested that the rubyinstaller for windows installer just doesn't contain that info anymore and I should use the online documentation, which, when I goto http://ruby-doc.org/downloads/ I discover that the version I am using (2.4.4) does not exist.

This is odd, because the rubyinstaller site specifically says that if I'm new to Ruby(which I am), I should install 2.4.4. You'd think that if any version had good documentation, it would be that one. Instead, it seems to be missing entirely.

This all started because I am trying to learn Ruby and am watching the Lynda.com course on Ruby by Kevin Skoglund, which was recorded many versions ago and in that course he refers to the ri command from the shell, which in my version doesn't work. see below:

> ruby --version
>   ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x64-mingw32]
>
> ri --version
>   ri.cmd 5.0.0
>
> ri String
>   Nothing known about String

Now, if it's not available within ruby using ri, and I have to use online documentation, AND it's missing for my version, which happens to be the version recommended for new users, … you see my frustration.

Here's what I really want...
1. I want to use ri and have it work.
2. If that's just not possible, I'd like to know where the documentation for my version is online, because it's not where it's supposed to be.

Any help is appreciated. If it involves installing anything, letting me know HOW to do that is also appreciated. As I mentioned, I'm new.

Comment: You can use any 2.4 documentation. 2.4.x are just bugfixes. And documentation is also installed by RubyInstaller (search for `API reference` in the Start menu).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the RubyInstaller, I will assume that you are on Windows.

I will open this by saying that I am not 100% on this, but I am pretty condfident in this answer.

- The "Use 2.4, not 2.5" was due to errors with Ruby Gem when Ruby 2.5
  was first released, as I happen to be on a Windows machine installing
  Ruby at that exact time, and that was the reasoning at that point not
  to use the newest 2.5 version.
- The above mentioned reason has since been corrected.

Realistically, if you are beginner, as long as you using documentation that is *close* to your version (2.0+ - 2.4-ish), it will be fine. Now obviously, and I shouldn't have to provide this disclaimer, though I will so to avoid the inevitable down-votes if I don't,  this is not 100% perfect solution and there will be very small differences. As a beginner, the likelihood of you encountering any of these differences are extremely low, low enough not to even worry about. There are missing and poorly documented sections of every language, and Ruby is no exception. Typically these are less used classes (though Ruby Fiddle is an exception that I hate how poorly documented it is), and will have no effect on your learning process as you learn the fundamentals and core of the language.

To my recollection, the "core" is rather well documented, and so long as you use documentation from 2.0+ (the closer to 2.4 the better), you should be completely fine, and it is exactly the same. The "standard library" may be slightly more hit or miss, and your mileage may vary a little more, yet still nothing too extreme.

So, to address the second part of your question, do not worry too hard about finding the EXACT version of documentation you are using. It may not even exist online, though the installer should have provided a CHM help file (there will be shortcut for it with the shortcuts for Ruby, IRB, etc.

As for "why" ri is not working, I am not 100% sure yet again. I am on ArchLinux, and RDoc doesn't even built. Honestly, RDoc is being left by the wayside for newer (and IMO better) document engine, namely YARD. A possible solution that I do, and prefer, is to install the YARD gem right after I install Ruby:

```
gem install yard
```

And then set YARD to generate my documentation with this in CMD:

```
yard config --gem-install-yri
```

If you decide to take this route, much more can be learned about it [here](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md).

The benefit with it is that it also supports RDoc and is backwards compatible.